# What new in Equinox 3.5.2?

Tags: osgi, equinox

The Eclipse and Equinox teams have released a new version of Equinox framework which is 3.5.2. I am currently using Equinox 3.5.0 and considering to upgrade to Equinox 3.5.2. However, I could not find any sites that mentions what is new in Equinox 3.5.2 and what bugs have been fixed in this new version, even in the website: http://download.eclipse.org/equinox/drops/R-3.5.2-201002111343/index.php#Framework

Does any one have experience in what is new in Equinox 3.5.2? Please share your experiences.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can find all information in [eclipse bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/).

[Here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?query_format=advanced;bug_status=RESOLVED;bug_status=VERIFIED;bug_status=CLOSED;target_milestone=3.5.2;product=Equinox) a list of issues that were resolved in 3.5.2